# Executing the Powershell command "Get-Volume" from within vb.net

Tags: vb.net, powershell-3.0

Using the Powershell ISE, I run the "Get-Volume" command and it produces the results below.

Header:

```
Drive FileSystemLabel FileSystem DriveType HealthStatus SizeRemaining Size
```

Detail:

```
C     NTFS            Fixed                Healthy      18.88 GB      59.4 GB
```

Now I want to extract out the SizeRemaining and Size from within a vb.net program.

Running the code below in debug and passing in the "Get-Volume" command, the collection variable cResults contains 1 entry:

(New System.Collections.Generic.Mscorlib_CollectionDebugView(Of System.Management.Automation.PSObject)(cResults)).Items(0)

{MSFT_Volume (ObjectId = "\?\Volume{8a68dbb9-122c-4890-a81e-bf70...)}

How do I get to the SizeRemaining and Size (18.88 GB      59.4 GB ) from this?

NOTE: if I run the code passing in "Get-Process", the collection variable cResults contains 43 System.Diagnostics.Process entries:

(New System.Collections.Generic.Mscorlib_CollectionDebugView(Of System.Management.Automation.PSObject)(cResults)).Items(0)

{System.Diagnostics.Process (conhost)}

and in this case I'm able to drill to the **BaseObject** and get to individual result fields for that command using the "myProcess." lines of code.

```
  RunScript("Get-Volume", diskViewData, StrMessage)


  Sub RunScript(ByVal scriptText As String, ByRef byRefDiskViewData As DiskViewData, ByRef byRefMessage As String)

    Dim runspace As Runspace

    Dim diskViewDataList As New DiskViewData

    Dim myProcess As System.Diagnostics.Process

    Try
        runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace()

        Try
             runspace.Open()

            Dim pipeline As Pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline()

            pipeline.Commands.AddScript(scriptText)

            ' Execute the script and add put result in a collection.
            Dim cResults As Collection(Of PSObject) = pipeline.Invoke()

            runspace.Close()

            If cResults.Count > 0 Then
                For Each obj As PSObject In cResults
                    Dim diskViewData As New DiskViewData

                    myProcess = obj.BaseObject

                    'diskViewData.Total_Size = (myProcess.?)
                    'diskViewData.Remaining_Space = (myProcess.?)

                Next
            Else
                byRefMessage = "Empty object returned after runnng the powershell command."
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            byRefMessage = "Failing AFTER create of runspace. " & ex.Message
        End Try
    Catch ex As Exception
        byRefMessage = "Failing at create of runspace. " & ex.Message
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Is it an option to do everything in powershell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, the result can be fetched easily using the [Properties collection of the PSObject class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.psobject.properties%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), like this:

```
' create PowerShell instance for the specified command
dim ps as PowerShell = PowerShell.Create().AddCommand("Get-Volume")
' iterate over the result
for each result as PSObject in ps.Invoke()
    ' results only for drive C
    if (result.Properties("DriveLetter").Value = "C") then
        ' access property using the Property properties collection
        Console.WriteLine("{0} - Total: {1}; Remaining: {2}", result.Properties("DriveLetter").Value, result.Properties("Size").Value, result.Properties("SizeRemaining").Value)
    end if
next result
```

The result is (you can format it using division by 1024 in order to get KB / MB / GB):

> C - Total: 1057254976; Remaining: 38872832

Comment: Thanks...where I had my 2 lines of commented code, I replaced them with a version of what you recommended.                         byRefDiskViewData.Total_Size = ((obj.Properties("Size").Value / 1024) / 1024) / 1024
byRefDiskViewData.Remaining_Space = ((obj.Properties("SizeRemaining").Value / 1024) / 1024) / 1024

Comment: Glad, that the answer helped.